# create function with property that can be accessed in and out of function scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function:

```
const fetchMovies = (function (query) {
  const requestId = this.requestId(query)
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendingRequest(requestId))
    return ajax.get(`/movies/search?q=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(receievedResponse(requestId))
        return dispatch(addMovies(res.data.movies))
      })
  }
}).bind({
  requestId: (query) => `fetchMoviesLoading-${query}`
})
```

This allows the `fetchMovies` function to have the `requestId` able to be called within itself. However, the `requestId` property cannot be accessed like so:

```
fetchMovies.requestId === undefined // true
```

Is there a simple/clean way to expose the `requestId`?

This just looks messy:

```
const fetchMoviesContext = {
  requestId: (query) => `fetchMoviesLoading-${query}`
}

const fetchMovies = (function (query) {
  const requestId = this.requestId(query)
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendingRequest(requestId))
    return ajax.get(`/movies/search?q=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(receievedResponse(requestId))
        return dispatch(addMovies(res.data.movies))
      })
  }
}).bind(fetchMoviesContext)
fetchMovies.requestId = fetchMoviesContext.requestId
```

Comment: It looks so messy because you wanna force the usage of `this` ...

Comment: Why do you want to access the method like that ? Do you have a use case? If it's a property for each function, maybe you should replace your function with a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
function fetchMovies(query) {
  const requestId = fetchMovies.requestId(query)
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendingRequest(requestId))
    return ajax.get(`/movies/search?q=${query}`)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(receievedResponse(requestId))
      return dispatch(addMovies(res.data.movies))
    })
  }
}
fetchMovies.requestId = (query) => `fetchMoviesLoading-${query}`;
```

Don't overcomplicate it.